# To ge the part of the String and Compare witha a variable(String Variable)

Tags: java, string, groovy

I have the String like:

```
String value = "13,14,15,16,17"
```

But i Dont know how many numbers are there with comma separation.

I want to compare with the variable say:

```
String varValue = "16"
```

It may be in any postion..

I want to compare these two string variables.... 
Please can anyone help?

Comment: What is the expected output of this comparison?

Comment: It seems unlikely that this is really related to C... nor can I see why Grails would be relevant...

Comment: So what have you tried ?

Comment: Is it `c` or `Java` question ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this sort of thing:

```
String values = '13,14,15,16,17'

String required = '16'

values.tokenize( ',' ).with { toks ->
  println "There are ${toks.size()} elements in the list"
  println "The list contains $required is ${toks.contains( required )}"
  println "It is at position ${toks.indexOf( required )}"
}
```

Which prints

```
There are 5 elements in the list
The list contains 16 is true
It is at position 3
```

Comment: What language is this in? I'm assuming C?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `split` method to put the numbers in an array and then compare.

Here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` method to receive an `Array`.  Turning the `Array` into a `List` will allow you to use some helper functions such as `contains` and `indexOf`, which can be used to return whether the token exists or the position of the token.

```
String value = "13,14,15,16,17";

//Checks existence
boolean contains = Arrays.asList(value.split(",")).contains("16");

//Returns position
int pos = Arrays.asList(value.split(",")).indexOf("16") + value.split(",").length + 1;
```

These examples all use Java.

Comment: only problem is if 116 is a number in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Do not quite understand your question.

> Dont know how many numbers are there with comma separation

use String method split()

> I want to compare with the variable say: String varValue = "16"

use String method contains()

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java , then following can be done to achieve this :
1. Split the input string into an array.
2. convert that array into a list .

Now 
a) To find total elements separated by comma , Use :
   size().

b) To find if the list contains required element or not , Use :
   contains().

c) To find position of element in list , Use :
   indexof()

So the code will look like :

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String inputString = "13,14,15,16,17";
    String element = "16";

    // Convert the string into array.
    String values[] = inputString.split(",");

    // Create a list using array elements.
    List<String> valList = Arrays.asList(values);

    System.out.println("Size :" + valList.size());
    System.out.println("List contains 5 " + valList.contains(element));
    System.out.println("Position of element" + valList.indexOf(element));
}
```

}